# Can't get php.ini to output error_log (Wordpress, Debian, OpenLiteSpeed)

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, debian, openlitespeed

After realizing I get an "Error 500" when updating/publishing a page (post.php), I checked if I had logs.

`display_logs` was `Off` in my php.ini file (Found with `php --ini`)

I checked on the OLS docs here: https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:php:enable-php-error_log

I had to add: `error_log = /var/log/php_error_log`

I also made sure to have `error_reporting = E_ALL`

Finally, I had to change `display_errors` to `On`

I then saved, verified it saved correctly and then forced another error 500 from post.php

No file "php_error_log" was created.

Do I need to create it myself?

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
I created a PHP page on my webserver's root to check if maybe I'm not using the right PHP.INI file.

I created a simple `1.php` file with this inside:

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?>
```

I then loaded the page and it's all blank.

**EDIT (2):**
Caught my error:

```
[STDERR] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Normalizer::isNormalized() in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/cloudflare/vendor/symfony/polyfill-intl-idn/Idn.php:338
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/cloudflare/vendor/symfony/polyfill-intl-idn/Idn.php(163): Symfony\Polyfill\Intl\Idn\Idn::process()
#1 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/cloudflare/vendor/symfony/polyfill-intl-idn/bootstrap.php(140): Symfony\Polyfill\Intl\Idn\Idn::idn_to_ascii()
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/cloudflare/src/WordPress/WordPressClientAPI.php(18): idn_to_ascii()
#3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/cloudflare/src/WordPress/Hooks.php(148): CF\WordPress\WordPressClientAPI->getZoneTag()
#4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/cloudflare/src/WordPress/Hooks.php(442): CF\WordPress\Hooks->purgeCacheByRelevantURLs()
#5 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): CF\WordPress\Hooks->purgeCacheOnPostStatusChange()
#6 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#7 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.p in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/cloudflare/vendor/symfony/polyfill-intl-idn/Idn.php on line 338
```

Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Make sure that the task owner that runs PHP has write access to the file and folder for your log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by Cloudflare plugin and identifiable via the OpenLiteSpeed error log.